# Defining type for ReactNative composite component

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm making a composite component. Then I have to define the type of it. For example, here is the sample composite component.

```js
const compositeComponent = ({ text, input }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text {...text}></Text>
      <TextInput {...input} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

What I want is defining the types 'text' and 'input'. But I couldn't get the type of `Text` and `TextInput`. How can I get the `Text` and `TextInput` tpyes and use it for composite component props type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I couldn't get the type of `Text` and `TextInput`

This is actually very easy!  If you need to get the type of a variable, you can use the [`typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator) like this: `typeof Text`.

(Note: The built-in React Native `Text` and `TextInput` are class components, and classes in typescript [are their own types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).  So you can use `Text` and `TextInput` as types for instances of those components.  However we want the type of the component itself rather than an instance so that is [still a case for `typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#advanced-techniques).)

This gives you the type of the *component*, not the props.  There are two things that we can do to get the prop types.

1. Look at the definitions for the component types and import the proper types from from React Native. (better approach)

```
import {TextProps, TextInputProps} from "react-native";
```

2. Work backwards from the component using the React utility type `ComponentProps`. (worse approach)

```
import {ComponentProps} from "react";
import {Text, TextInput} from "react-native";

type TextProps = ComponentProps<typeof Text>

type TextInputProps = ComponentProps<typeof TextInput>
```

Now we can define the types for the `CompositeComponent` (which should be uppercase) using the props for the individual components.

```
interface CompositeComponentProps {
    text: TextProps;
    input: TextInputProps;
}

const CompositeComponent = ({ text, input }: CompositeComponentProps) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text {...text}></Text>
      <TextInput {...input} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the below code:

```
const CompositeComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text {...props.textProps}>{props.text}</Text>
      <TextInput {...props.inputProps} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

In The Screen or Component where you are about to use the Composite Component.

```
<CompositeComponent 
    textProps={
       style={{ fontSize: 16, color: 'black' }}
    }
    inputProps={
       onChangeText={(enteredText) => { console.log('process your enteredText here'); }}
       style={{ fontSize: 16, color: 'black' }} 
    }
    text="Enter TEXT here to show in the textView"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do this the warning comes up in CompositeComponent with `Binding element 'Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.`.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript ?

Comment: Yes :) So, I have to define the type of the props of CompositeComponent

Comment: Yes, You must have to define the types for the props